# Can excessive masturbation cause acne?

Tags: environmental-health, masturbation, acne

Many people believe excessive masturbation causes acne, among many other things (e.g. hair loss and erectile dysfunction - off topic for this question).

One such site that claims or supports this is [Herballove](http://www.herballove.com/article.asp?art=614)

> His chronic over-masturbation resulted in acne outbreak, hair loss and
>   erectile dysfunction at age 24.

The answer further says in response of having body acne, hair loss and ED:

> All of your symptoms can result from sexual exhaustion as a result of
>   your chronic over-masturbation

It is further explained in the answer

> Acne is caused by a number of factors, including diet, stress,
>   accumulation of dead skin cells, bacteria in the pores, use of
>   steroids, poor hygiene, drugs and medication. **In addition, acne can
>   be caused by over-ejaculation.**

Further:

> Excessive sex and masturbation can increase histamine, the super
>   hormone DHT, the stress neurohormone epinephrine, and the inflammatory
>   hormone prostaglandin E2 to induce acne outbreak.

This is just one of the site, there are many out there. Is this true?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)! We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people. You've provided a reference to a to  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. A claim from 1888, and two claims from a [Poe's Law](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Poe's_Law) site, like  [Christwire](http://christwire.org) aren't really good enough.

Comment: @Oddthinking, while I agree that this question could use a little editing work, there is absolutely no reason to close it. A quick search shows that there **are** people out there who believe this.

Comment: @SamIAm - I suspect there is more to this closing than was cited.  Like, perhaps the questioner is already suspended on his other account.

Comment: This could actually be true but there is not much research done in this here. Obviously pimples are caused by masturbation only :)

Comment: @Chad: Nope. No ulterior motive (although I would say that, wouldn't I?) If this user has another account, I am unaware of it. I do plan to ask a meta-question about Poe's Law sites, though. I'm not convinced I took the right line, and would like to consult with the community on what the policy should be.

Comment: @Oddthinking - This question just looks a lot like the questions asked by another user who is currently suspended for account irregularity's... so I guess i just assumed.

Comment: This is like the other myth that if you masturbate too much you become blind (and imagine what happens if you rub your eyes too much!).

Comment: No this is a false claim by 7th day adventists (such as Mr. Kellogg), who have a ridiculous antiscientific agenda against masturbation. There are plenty of studies ridiculing this (but I can't access them at the moment): do see [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1746-1561.1976.tb03099.x/abstract)!

Comment: I thought that acne cause masturbation? :)

Answer (score 19):

**No.** No amount of masturbation ("excessive" or otherwise) causes acne.

Self-help forum and product retailer, Acne.org explain on their [Acne Myth](http://www.acne.org/myths.html) page:

> This antiquated notion, originating as early as the 17th century to dissuade young people from having premarital sex, is not based on scientific evidence.

### Masturbation and Acne

Is there a correlation between acne and masturbation? I do not answer this in this answer, but I do argue any correlation is weak, and I look at other ways acne and masturbation *might* be correlated, and yet still not be causally related.

*For this discussion, "acne" is regarded as a full-blown severe case covering substantial areas of skin, and not the occasional lonely zit.*

### Correlation, if any, is weak

The number of people with acne is much lower than the number of people who masturbate.

From the [Planned Parenthood Federation of America](http://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-topics/sex-101/masturbation-23901.htm):

> Masturbation is very common. Studies show that about 7 out of 10 adult men and more than 5 out of 10 adult women masturbate. It’s also common for children and teens to masturbate.

From [Acne.org](http://www.acne.org/adult-acne.html):

> Adult acne affects 25% of all adult men and 50% of adult women at some time in their adult lives

So, looking at the male population, 70% of male masturbate only 25% have acne. (The numbers for women are closer.)

If there is a correlation between masturbation and correlation it can't be a strong one. Masturbation doesn't automatically lead to acne.

### Hormones

Hormones may cause acne.

Acne.org argues on their [Acne Myth page](http://www.acne.org/myths.html) that any correlation may be caused by androgens:

> A more plausible explanation may be that higher levels of androgens (male sex hormones) can cause increased sex drive. We also know that high levels of androgens can be related to more severe cases of acne. So it may be the higher androgen levels and not the associated increase in desire for sexual activity that is related to acne.

Testosterone is an androgren that is related to acne and sex-drive and hence might be related to masturbation.

[The relation of testosterone and acne](http://acne.about.com/od/acnetriggers/a/hormones.htm):

> Most dermatologists believe acne is closely linked with hormonal changes that occur within the body. In fact, testosterone has been identified as a chief trigger of acne development. According to the American Academy of Dermatology, testosterone works to stimulate oil gland activity, creating an oilier skin more prone to acne breakouts.

Sources for this have also been:

- The Wikipedia article for [masturbation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation#Health_and_psychological_effects)
- One of Wikipedia's cited [sources](http://www.springerlink.com/content/g24qw076248406u4/)

### Masturbation and Other Effects

A separate concept is what constitutes "excessive" masturbation. From Planned Parenthood Federation of America's [Myth and Facts about Masturbation page](http://www.plannedparenthood.org/info-for-teens/sex-masturbation/myths-facts-about-masturbation-33824.htm) largely dismissed the idea:

> The myth is that too much masturbation will make you blind, crazy, or stupid, damage your sex organs, or stunt your growth.  Some people masturbate every day — or even more than once a day. That's fine. So is there such a thing as "too much" masturbation? According to the experts (the American Psychiatric Association), it's only when masturbation gets in the way of daily activities — like going to school or work, or meeting friends — that it would be considered "too much." And not many people have that problem.
>
> Also, some people worry that masturbating frequently will affect a girl's ability to get pregnant or a guy's ability to produce sperm. It doesn't.
>
> Some people masturbate daily or more than once a day, some people masturbate once in a while, and some people never masturbate

However, I think that it's worth noting that they may be some negative side-effects to masturbation:

If a couple is trying to get pregnant the man should hold off from masturbation on the days before the woman's ovulation and only have sex (once a day or every other day) as it reduces the sperm count and will reduce the chance of successful fertilization, see [here](http://www.justmommies.com/getting-pregnant/having-problems-getting-pregnant/can-too-much-sex-harm-your-chances-getting-pregnan) and [here](http://ezinearticles.com/?5-Tips-Men-Should-Know-for-Conceiving-a-Baby-Boy-Or-Girl&id=5042035).

You can read more about the negative effects of masturbation [here](http://www.askmen.com/dating/love_tip_500/500b_negative-side-effects-of-masturbation.html)

Comment: *> so that people who are more prone to acne, are also more inclined to masturbate more often and have more sex (the irony of nature, the people who want sex more, get acne which prevents it)*

So true!

Comment: *Having active sexual life or not doesn't affect hormonal status*: I would remove this sentence. For instance, orgasm produces a prolactin increase both in men and women and I am pretty sure that other hormones also change during long periods of abstinence. Other than that I agree with you: +1.

Comment: All of the claims here lack *specific*, *scientific* references and some of them are patently false. The overall conclusion is (most probably!) true but this answer in its current form is inacceptable.

Comment: @nico, I've added a clarification about it. I hope it's clear that while there is a small change in hormone levels, they are neither permanent not related to acne.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I've added some sources, I hope that clears it, and again I refer you to section b, I've asked 2 doctors (my GF and Mother) and they both agreed and gave the explanations given in sections c,d and e. I can't give those sources, as they are answers given in real life conversations.

Comment: @Ilya Two things: personal contacts are not a valid reference here since they cannot be easily checked. Regarding the claims about hormones in particular, these need to be referenced. For instance, you *claim* that masturbation releases (only) oxytocin, only has a short-term effect on hormonal balance, and that short-term hormonal variations have no influence on acne. All three claims must be corroborated. And finally, the following is simply false, as far as I know: “Your reproductive system functions the same way weather you have sexual activity or not”.

Comment: I don't care if you personally talked to 100 doctors, that doesn't mean anything, especially not for Skeptics.SE's answer's standards. I've had doctors tell me things that was in conflict with current research. I agree 100% with @Konrad. Point a is just a false argument, point c is complete speculation, among other problems. This sentence "psychological... affects of masturbation... is reversible if you hold off for few days" Huh, what does that mean? Also, needs citation. Are you telling me if I don't masturbate for a few days I will no longer feel shame about masturbation?

Comment: @Sam I am, no, the shame won't disaper, but if you have problem reaching climax during sex due to masturbation, holding off for few days, will help. As to the guilt, if you have it you sould consoult a profesional. If masturbation leads to acne, then most people will have acne as most people maturbate or/and have sex. c. is a speculation, as I said that it _could_ couse, not that it couses at all times.

Comment: I've brought 2 citation from credible sources answering simply the question and saying no. As I searched this online, I've seen that this myth is common, and that people have seen coralation between the two, I've brought several explanations to explain that observed coralation as well as real possible bad sideaffects of masturbation.

Comment: The question asked about the effects of excessive masturbation. This means masturbating more than the average person does. Therefore the argument that there are a lot of people who do masturbate and don't have acne doesn't help.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed acne.org doesn't say that there evidence that excessive masturbation doesn't cause masturbation. It just speculates about how the myth came about. The Planed Parenthood website you linked to doesn't even speak about acne. Both websites don't cite any study that provides empiric evidence about whether excessive masturbation can cause acne. On this website "credible source for medical claims" means either a scientific study or a website that cites a scientific study.

Comment: @Christian, There is no such thing as "excessive masturbation". The only time that masturbation becomes excessive is when it interferes with every day life. There are no studies about it because of it. Planed Parenthood cites the American Psychiatric Association on this issue.

Comment: "but if you have problem reaching climax during sex due to masturbation, holding off for few days, will help" [citation needed - I remain very very skeptical, depends on why you aren't reaching climax, plus it is completely off topic] I personally have no guilt about masturbation, it was just an example.

Comment: "If masturbation leads to acne, then most people will have acne as most people masturbate." This is a false argument. First of all how do you know most adults don't have acne? Because you don't see it? Personally, I am an adult who has a lot of acne, but the general population doesn't know, since it is in a spot that is normally covered by clothes. That is like saying "cold sores outbreaks aren't triggered by the menstrual cycle because all normal healthy women menstruate and I don't see them with cold sores" [Hint: they are](http://jid.oxfordjournals.org/content/59/1/60.extract)

Comment: @Sam I am, seriously, you don't see the word "Possible"!? Some people may fill guild other won't. As well as the climax things, some people may find reaching climax during sex hard due to the reason included, not necessarily. If you find it hard due to this reason, then holding off will solve it. If it's due to other reasons, then obviously this is not related. And **it's** off topic of acne, I put it there as an extra about the real possible problems of masturbation. The citation is in the fallowing sentence.

Comment: @Sam I Am, Added the sources to back up the first claim.

Comment: Guys, we are speaking about *causality*. The claim is: you masturbate -> you get acne. This is obviously false, and I have not seen any proof whatsoever in favour of it. All the rest about guilt, failure to have orgasm etc. is absolutely irrelevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: @nico: No, the claim isn't "masturbate -> you get acne" it's "masturbate a lot -> you are more likely to get acne". Attacking strawman doesn't help.

Comment: @Christian: guilt and failure of having orgasm still have nothing to do about it. My point is that it is a medical claim, pseudo-morality and religion should stay out of it.

Comment: @nico, Christian, Sam and all those that had problems with the guilt and other negative affects part. I have edited it so that it's clear now (in my opinion) that it comes as a side note and not as an answer to the main question. If it still bothers you I'll consider deleting that part entirely.

Comment: I have been substantially editing this answer. At this stage, it still isn't at the point where I would recommend an upvote, but it has fewer unreferenced claims and digressions and is starting to get some structure.

Comment: "So, looking at the male population, 70% of male masturbate only 25% have acne. ... If there is a correlation between masturbation and correlation it can't be a strong one. Masturbation doesn't automatically lead to acne." This logic is invalid; one presumes that not everybody who masturbates gets acne. If for example 90% of people with acne masturbated, that would be a significant correlation--indeed, there may be a correlation due to people with acne being more likely to masturbate. Though I doubt there is a significant correlation, a proper study would be needed to confirm this.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.